Obtaining a Schengen visa after penalty period
Has anyone successfully obtained a short-stay visa to Denmark after completing a penalty period? Or is it generally challenging to get a visa again once a penalty period has been imposed?

Put yourself in the shoes of the officer who will examine the application: "This person told us before that they would leave the country in time, and they didn't. Why should I trust them now?" Unless your circumstances have changed significantly, yes, this big red flag will be the first thing they'll consider. At the very least, forget about applying for a new visa shortly after your ban expires.

In any case it will be more challenging: the application will have more scrutiny, and also on arrival, at immigration check. Also your statements will have less trust: so you should be stronger and independent proofs. But nothing is impossible, and after some years people (and their life) changes. (e.g. a young student, but now has a reputable job and history of travel). -- In short: it really depends on the case and reason of the ban: we cannot easily answer (and most people here do not have ban experience: we like to travel, and so some budget, so we are careful on that).
